# Genealogy Chat week of 18 December 2015 | Location, Location, Location

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Place names and boundaries change over time, but our genealogy software often encourages us to standardize on a particular set of place names.  But knowing the historical jurisdictions of the time can be crucial when you want to find a record.

What are your favorite tools and techniques for keeping track of the families that don't move at all, but the borders are shifting around them?

Share your favorite sites with historical maps, archives which have special collections about places you wouldn't expect, and other ideas for finding elusive records.

Come chat about it in the [Conference Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) -- ask questions, share your experiences. And if you solve a problem or make a new discovery because of the chat, don't forget to write up what you learned in a self-answered question.

The chat will occur in The Conference Room all week long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get an alert each week.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event! and they might be used in an upcoming week!