# Genealogy Chat week of 25 December 2015 | New Genealogy Toys?

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Did you discover new websites, get new software or hardware, a new subscription or new records, or receive new DNA test results?

Come chat about what's new in the [Conference Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) -- ask questions, share your experiences. And if you solve a problem or make a new discovery because of the chat, don't forget to write up what you learned in a self-answered question.

The chat will occur in The Conference Room all week long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get an alert each week.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event! and they might be used in an upcoming week!