# Weekly Chat: Finding hidden records | week of 20 May 2016

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat, challenge

Our weekly chat and topic challenge this week is to explore how we can find records in unexpected places.  For instance -- if you can't find someone's marriage in BMDs or vital records, there may be information about it in military records, land records, or other records where providing proof of a marriage was necessary.

Have you found records in unexpected places? Share your experiences by chatting or by writing a self-answered question -- or both!

The chat will occur in [the Conference Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all week long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!