# Weekly Chat / Challenge: Have you reviewed your research lately?

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat, challenge

For this week's chat, a challenge: Have you reviewed your prior research lately?  What about your questions and answers here on G&FH.SE -- have you learned about new resources that have come online since you wrote them?

Let's take this opportunity to freshen up the place by adding new material to our questions or answers, or writing new self-answered questions to demonstrate how we solved a problem.

Come chat about how you learned new things by going over your research with a fresh eye -- and brag about the new sites you've found.

---

The chat will occur in [the Conference Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all week long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!