# Weekly Chat: Turning the model upside down | week of 29 July 2016

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Inspired by a post from *The Ancestry Insider*: [Turning the Model Upside Down](http://www.ancestryinsider.org/2016/07/turning-model-upside-down-byugen-byufhgc.html), who was reporting on Steve Rockwood's keynote address given at the 2016 BYU Conference on Family History and Genealogy.

> Steve is president and chief executive officer (CEO) of FamilySearch
>   International. He is the managing director of the Family History
>   Department of The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints, which
>   sponsors FamilySearch.
>
> Steve said in the past we presented people with a chart or a computer
>   to start them in family history. Those that were willing to stay with
>   it long enough eventually experienced the positive emotions associated
>   with family history. In the Church today, that amounts to 2% of the
>   members.

FamilySearch has changed their logo to a set of picture frames, and has shifted the emphasis to "start[ing] people with photos, audio recordings, anything that anyone can participate in." This change in emphasis was evident at the 2016 RootsTech conference, where the emphasis was on applications that make it easier to collect family stories.

Let's talk about how a change in outlook from 'filling in the blanks on a form' to an emphasis on narrative makes a difference in how we 'do genealogy'.

Thanks to [ACProctor](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/108/acproctor) for his pointer to this blog post.

---

The chat will occur in [the Conference Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all week long the first week of each month. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!