# Weekly Topic challenge: correlating military service records with other sources?

Tags: discussion, challenge

In honor of Remembrance Day / Armistice Day / Veterans Day --

This topic challenge is about taking clues found in military records and following them up in other records, and / or using identifiers in military records to show that the service record you have found belongs to the person you are looking for.

Post new questions, post new answers to the older questions on the site -- self-answer to show off your research.

Resources:

- UK residents: free access to military records at Ancestry UK:

> †Access to the records in the featured collections will be free until
>   13 November, 2016 at 23:59 GMT. To view these records you will need to
>   register for free with Ancestry.co.uk with your name and email
>   address. We will then send you a username and password to access the
>   records. After the free access period ends, you will only be able to
>   view the records in the featured collections using an Ancestry paid
>   membership. To see a full list of the records in the featured
>   collections please [click here](http://www.ancestry.co.uk/s74249/t35582/rd.ashx).

- [findmypast military records](http://www.findmypast.com/military-records)

> We've made our entire collection of 70 million world military records FREE from 10-13 November 2016.

Comment: For anyone looking for earlier questions about World War I, to try and help solve one or more, here is a link: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-war-1

Comment: Ancestry.ca also has "free access to all Canadian military records", to Nov. 13