# Weekly Chat: using 'born digital' databases and index-only databases | week of 18 Nov 2016

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Let's talk about the challenges of using online databases that don't have any images attached.

two new sites which are a huge boon for those of us studying family history in England, Wales, and the US.

In England and Wales, there is the new [GRO online searchable index](https://www.gro.gov.uk/gro/content/certificates/login.asp) that is connected with their pilot program for ordering PDFs of birth and death registrations. [FAQ: Most Customers Want to Know](https://www.gro.gov.uk/gro/content/certificates/most_customers_want_to_know.asp)

In the US, the US National Archives (NARA) has added some of the Social Security Administration's NUMIDENT files to its [Access to Archival Databases (AAD)](https://aad.archives.gov/aad/) website.  [FAQ: Series: Numerical Identification (NUMIDENT) Files, 1936 2007 Record Group 47](https://aad.archives.gov/aad/content/aad_docs/rg047_numid_faq.pdf)

Both these systems allow us to access for free information held by the respective governments for people whose births and deaths fall within certain guidelines. In many cases we can get exact dates of birth or death, or both, and clues to places of birth, death, or residences of relatives.

Let's talk about how you have used the information in these databases to confirm your previous guesses or to show you possible paths for further research.

---

The chat will occur in [the Conference Room](https://www.gro.gov.uk/gro/content/certificates/login.asp) all week long the first week of each month. Be sure to [register yourself](https://aad.archives.gov/aad/) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!