# Genealogy Chat week of 27 Jan 2017 | Making the most of your conference experience

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

As we're all looking forward to [RootsTech2017](https://www.rootstech.org/rootstech-2017), which takes place from 8-11 February, let's talk about going to conferences -- whether in person, or via live-streamed video.  How do you decide what sessions to attend, and how do you take what you learned and apply it to your research after the conference is over?  Which kind of talks draw your attention, and why? Who are your must-watch speakers?

For information about the RootsTech App, see the Ancestry Insider's post [Whether You’re Going to #RootsTech or Not](http://www.ancestryinsider.org/2017/01/whether-youre-going-to-rootstech-or-not.html), or [view the schedule on your desktop](http://app.core-apps.com/rootstech2017/events/tracks/Track?include_day=true) at the app-maker's site.  (And a big thanks to Randy Seaver's post [RootsTech 2017 Live Streaming Schedule](http://www.geneamusings.com/2017/01/rootstech-2017-live-streaming-schedule.html) on Geneamusings for the [link to the live-streaming schedule](https://www.rootstech.org/live-stream-schedule)!)

---

The chat will occur in [The Conference Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-conference) all week long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get an alert each week.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!