# Weekly chat: writing things down -- research plans, journals, and logs | week of 10 Mar 2017

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

This week let's talk about ways to keep track of what you're doing with your research.  This week's chat was inspired by a webinar at FamilySearch by David Dilts on using research logs -- but logs are only one part of the research process.

[image]

---

The chat will occur in [the Conference Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all week long the first week of each month. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!