# Weekly Chat: | What I learned at the 2016 SCGS Genealogy Jamboree | week of 10 Jun 2016

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Each June, the Southern California Genealogical Society holds their annual conference, the [Genealogy Jamboree](http://genealogyjamboree.com/).  This year's Jamboree is from **3 to 5 June**.

Some sessions are streamed live and are available to the public to view for free (thanks to Ancestry, who sponsors the live stream) but remote viewers need to register in advance.  After the conference is over, the sessions are available to view again through **July 5, 2016**, but only if you have registered.

To see an overview of the sessions and to register, visit [Understanding Live Streaming for Jamboree](http://genealogyjamboree.com/2016/streaming-overview.html).  The [list of streamed sessions](http://genealogyjamboree.blogspot.com/2016/05/jamboree-2016-registration-now-open-for.html) is available on the Jamboree blog.

If you want to see the full schedule of sessions, you can download the [Pink Sheet](http://genealogyjamboree.com/2016/storage/PinkSheet-Jamboree.pdf), or you can view the [list of speakers](http://genealogyjamboree.com/2016/speakers.html).

---

Let's talk about the live-streamed sessions we watched, and the sessions we wish we could have seen, during the week of June 10 through the 16th.

The chat will occur in [the Conference Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all week long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!