# Weekly Chat: DNA Research -- the Good, The Bad, The Ugly | week of 15 July 2016

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

If you could design the ideal genealogical DNA-testing and match-analying service, what would it be?

What features are great, which not-so-good, which are really ugly?  Explain your "If I were master of the genealogical universe" solutions during the weekly chat.

---

The chat will occur in [the Conference Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all week long the first week of each month. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!