# Genealogy Chat: Prompts: help or hindrance? | week of 24 Feb 2017

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Topic Challenges. Blogging Prompts.  That presentation on a special topic that you just saw at a genealogical society or at the Family History Library.  Do they give your research a needed boost of energy, or are they just a BSO (Bright Shiny Object) that distracts you from your research?

Come talk about it this week in our weekly chat!

---

The chat will occur in [The Conference Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-conference) all week long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get an alert each week.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!